# When loading an external URL in a Webview/UIWebView, is it possible to load a local JS file?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, webview

In trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402447/error-loading-external-url-in-phonegap-2-5) where I ran into problems with iOS on Phonegap, I realized that I need to load two different `cordova.js` files depending on whether it's the iOS or the  Android application. One solution is to test server-side and link to a different `cordova.js` file, but I was trying to figure out if I could just bundle a platform-specific `cordova.js` file with each application.

Is it possible to do something like this on Android:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/phonegap-2.5.0.js, 15000);
```

and something similar in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just hit different endpoints, or use different paramaters for each platform and let the server handle it.

That said you could do something like this:

```
 - (void)downloadHTMLAndUpdateCordova
 {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someapi.com"];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
       NSError* error = nil;
       NSData *htmlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:self.request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

      if (error == nil) {
          NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[htmlData bytes]];
          htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"someCordovaFile.js" withString:@"someCordovaFileiOS.js"];
          [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:@"http://www.someapi.com"];
       }
 }
```