# Resetting plugins due to page load - Issue

Tags: cordova

After upgrading to Phonegap 2.5 from 2.3 Xcode hangs on this message "Resetting plugins due to page load".

I have reviewed all these answers:

[Error loading external URL in Phonegap 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402447/error-loading-external-url-in-phonegap-2-5)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569327/cordova-2-5-0-query-regarding-ios-plugin

[Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527120/failed-to-load-webpage-with-error-frame-load-interrupted)

which tell you to move cordova-2.5.0.js to the root (same level as index.html) but this didn't fix the issue for me.

I originally had the file in "js/cordova-2.5.0.js" and my index file has the same reference. I made the change as above and I got the same failed result.

After using the "create" command to upgrade and going through the process I've used

"cordova-2.5.0.js"
"/cordova-2.5.0.js"
"js/cordova-2.5.0.js"

I'm performing a "hard clean" every time I change it too.

any ideas what else I can try or what I'm missing?

Comment: You should be able to put the js anywhere you like as long as you specify the path correctly when including it inside the html page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using Jquery Mobile or something similar? I had the same issue as i had a login page which it would skip if you were already logged in.

Looks like there is an issue when fading from the splash screen and doing a hash change at the same time.

My code before

```
$('#LoginPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("UserID"))
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#MainPage");
        appRefresh();
    }
});
```

My code after

```
$('#LoginPage').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("UserID"))
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#MainPage", {changeHash: false});
        appRefresh();
    }
});
```

This is now working for me.

There is an issue log for this

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2602

Answer (score 9):

This can also occur if you have an error in your JavaScript file.

Comment: Curious about the down vote. I had this exact error message and it was in fact due to an error in my JavaScript file. This was intended to help someone else in my case that came to this page due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS app I'm also experiencing this issue - in the xcode console while running in the iOS Simulator I frequently see the msg: "Resetting plugins due to page load." and the app screen is blank.

The app stack is: 
  Phonegap 2.7,
  jQuery 2.0,
  jQuery-mobile 1.3.1,
  iPhone 6.1 simulator

I rolled back some of the js libs and found that by reverting back to jquery 1.9.1,
the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 is meant to be used with the jQuery 1.9.1 release (potentially also the new 1.10.x updates too) jQuery 2.0 strips out a lot of the backwards compatibility stuff which jQuery Mobile still uses.