# Phonegap/Cordova 3.1 Resetting plugins due to page load

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a fresh build of a iOS Phonegap/Cordova 3.1 hello world application and I am getting the following message in the xcode output :

```
2013-10-30 08:20:17.768 HelloWorld[51492:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES

**2013-10-30 08:20:17.914 HelloWorld[51492:c07] Resetting plugins due to page load.**

2013-10-30 08:20:18.394 HelloWorld[51492:c07] Finished load of:
```

What is causing the `Resetting plugins due to page load` message? The application appears to run fine when I build it.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile? if so, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858879/resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-issue

Comment: @seanxe no its a fresh build of the hello world application.

Comment: strange! not really a direct solution, but they've just released v3.2. maybe try upgrading and see if it's a bug that was fixed? http://cordova.apache.org/#news

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Resetting plugins due to page load - Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858879/resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-issue) on this very site.

It appears to be a known conflict with jQuery Mobile and similar libraries. Check the other post for a very simple remedy to this.

**EDIT:**

Thanks and I stand corrected, @bart_88. I looked in the Cordova project code and see the following:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView {  
 NSLog(@"Resetting plugins due to page load.");  
 [_commandQueue resetRequestId];  
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginResetNotification object:self.webView]];  
}
```

It appears that this code will be hit (CDVViewController) no matter what, so the message you are seeing is just a new NSLog entry that can be ignored.

Comment: Not using jQuery or jQuery Mobile