# Worklight 6.1 - Sometime app stuck with splash screen in IOS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I observed so many times that app get stuck with splash screen and nothing happens in this case. We are getting below logs on Xcode console at that time.

```
2014-01-20 13:09:14.822 MyApp[4326:a0b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-01-20 13:09:34.924 MyApp[4326:a0b] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
```

This is just a default application with index.html page and text `Hello Worklight` in it.

This is tested on `IOS6` and `IOS7` simulator and device both.

Comment: Uhm, there's nothing really to investigate here... Does this happen with a blank new app for iOS that does nothing, and tested **against your own development server**, or with your real app **in a production environment**? Details vishal....

Comment: Yes it is happening with both for sample app and production app. First i thought may be something wrong with production app then i tried with sample blank app. So it is for both.

Comment: but in the production environment where you have time out problems, or in your local development server?

Comment: Don't combine production issue...this is the issue while doing multiple project. So it is coming with blank worklight project or you can say any xcode worklight project with connect on startup false. It is issue regarding app stuçk with splash and nothing happen after that. Did you get the point.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this so you need to see what is the missing element here. Simulator or device? A specific iOS version or all?

Comment: @IdanAdar Please check updated question for IOS version on which i have tested.

Comment: Does this happen if after running the app in the simulator device from Xcode, you press the Stop button in Xcode and then run the app again, but by clicking on the app icon in the device/simulator?

Answer (score 2):

I found some similar posts at the following locations describing this issue with Phonegap/Cordova. Some of the solutions/suggestions may help:

[Phonegap/Cordova 3.1 Resetting plugins due to page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671249/phonegap-cordova-3-1-resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load)

[Resetting plugins due to page load - Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858879/resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-issue)

As well as a bug report in Cordova:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2602

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in worklight 6.2 + iOS 6(with a fix) that might also solve your problem, if you're having the same issue.

[IBM Worklight - App hang at splash screen after applying FixPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864978/ibm-worklight-app-hang-at-splash-screen-after-applying-fixpack/25144194#25144194)